# Jquery to select div (added by Ajax call) not work but with out Ajax call it works

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I've got a custom checkbox but my problem is that when I create with Ajax call the second div `#test_checkbox_ajax` jquery to select the checked input doesn't work, but the first div `#test_checkbox` and it's Jquery work perfectly. I need that the div create with Ajax call because most of my code work with Ajax call. How can I solve this? Anyone can help me please? if there is some question similar can you repot me so that I can try to get the solution. Thank You Very Much in Advance.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $.when(loadProfile()).done(function(res){
    addProfile(res);
  }).fail(function(resp) {
    if(resp.status!=408) {
      //error
    } else {
      //other
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test_checkbox input').on('click', function() {  //this work perfectly
    console.log('enter');
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      alert('checked');
    } else {
      alert('not checked');
    }
  });
  
  $('#test_checkbox_ajax input').on('click', function() { //this not work why??
    console.log('enter');
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      alert('checked');
    } else {
      alert('not checked');
    }
  });
});

function loadProfile() {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "GESINTRANET",
    data: "TPMAP=INSEGN"
  });
}

function addProfile(res) {
  $('#test_checkbox_ajax').empty();
  $('#test_checkbox_ajax').append('<label class="custom_single_label">Area</label>');
  $.each(res.aree, function(i, area) {
    $('#test_checkbox_ajax').append('<label class="custom_single_checkbox_container">' + area.nome + '<input type="checkbox" class="custom_checkbox" value="' + area.id + '"><span class="custom_checkbox_span"></span></label>');
  });
}
```

```css
/* custom input type: checkbox */

div.custom_checkbox_container {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}

div.custom_checkbox_container label.custom_single_label {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #222222;
  margin: 0;
}

div.custom_checkbox_container label.custom_single_checkbox_container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #222222;
  -moz-user-select: none; /* firefox 4.0+ */
  -o-user-select: none; /* Opera 10.5+ */
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ & Chrome 4.0+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0;
}

div.custom_checkbox_container label.custom_single_checkbox_container input.custom_checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div.custom_checkbox_container label.custom_single_checkbox_container span.custom_checkbox_span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 0;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #d4d7d9;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div.custom_checkbox_container label.custom_single_checkbox_container span.custom_checkbox_span:after {
  left: 4px;
  top: 1px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* firefox 4.0+ */
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Opera 10.5+ */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari 3.1+ & Chrome 4.0+ */
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

div.custom_checkbox_container label.custom_single_checkbox_container span.custom_checkbox_span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

div.custom_checkbox_containerlabel.custom_single_checkbox_container input.custom_checkbox ~ span.custom_checkbox_span {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

div.custom_checkbox_container label.custom_single_checkbox_container input.custom_checkbox:checked ~ span.custom_checkbox_span {
  background-color: #1a4c7f;
}

div.custom_checkbox_container label.custom_single_checkbox_container input.custom_checkbox:checked ~ span.custom_checkbox_span:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom_checkbox_container" id="test_checkbox">
  <label class="custom_single_label">Vehicle</label>
  <label class="custom_single_checkbox_container">Bike
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom_checkbox" value="bike">
    <span class="custom_checkbox_span"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="custom_single_checkbox_container">Car
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom_checkbox" value="car">
    <span class="custom_checkbox_span"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="custom_checkbox_container" id="test_checkbox_ajax">
</div>
```

Best Regards
Amila Fernando

Comment: Here issue it that loadProfile method inject the input tag where you intended to add the event which is called on load, but you are assigning events on elements in "onReady" which triggers before onLoad. So while assigning events dom is not populated and listeners are not assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach your event handler to the `document` or any appropriate parent element which is not being updated with ajax update. Refer **Delegated event handlers** section in [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation page.
For example, change

```
$('#test_checkbox input').on('click', function() {  //this work perfectly
    console.log('enter');
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      alert('checked');
    } else {
      alert('not checked');
    }
  });
```

to

```
$(document).on('click','#test_checkbox input', function() {  //this work perfectly
    console.log('enter');
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      alert('checked');
    } else {
      alert('not checked');
    }
  });
```

Edit:
As per the suggestion of @WernerPotgieter attached listener to `document` instead of `body`. Though I have added an example with event listener attached to document we should avoid excessive use of document or body for delegated events on large documents and must attach the listener to a location as close as possible to the target element for better performance.

Comment: just change `$('body')` to `$(document)`

Comment: @WernerPotgieter Makes sense but attaching many delegated event handlers to the document may degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery compares all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. Though I have added an example for the body we should avoid excessive use of document or body for delegated events on large documents.

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you are saying. But there is no difference between the two in the end. He can always just create the event listener when he generates the HTML. Or if need be to turn off the event listener when it is not needed anymore. There is a lot of ways around this.

Comment: Agreed. Updated the answer.